# NuGet Push Failure in TFS build

Tags: tfs, build, nuget, push

**Preface:** I am running NuGet Server (2.11.3) on Windows 2012 R2 / IIS 8.5. The NuGet Server manages its packages folder in separated file server (shared folder).
Additionally I am running TFS build machine (agent from TFS 2015) that uses this nuget server for both restore and push activities. Naturally,  each build, initially, reads the target solution >>> projects >>> packages.config files and restores the configured packages from the nuget server. On late step, the agent generates the required *.nupkg files and pushes them to the nuget endpoint of the same nuget server. Those are dependencies of other solutions.

**Problem:** the majority of the solutions running properly without any special issues. There are couple of solutions that only 1-3 projects within them, fail the TFS build with the following message:

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe
```

The IIS logs on nuget server looks like the following:

```
2017-03-27 16:47:26 192.168.2.116 PUT /MainRepository/nuget/ - 80 - 192.168.1.30 NuGet+Command+Line/3.5.0+(Microsoft+Windows+NT+6.2.9200.0) - 500 0 0 15
2017-03-27 16:47:26 192.168.2.116 PUT /MainRepository/nuget/ - 80 - 192.168.1.30 NuGet+Command+Line/3.5.0+(Microsoft+Windows+NT+6.2.9200.0) - 500 0 0 15
2017-03-27 16:47:26 192.168.2.116 PUT /MainRepository/nuget/ - 80 - 192.168.1.30 NuGet+Command+Line/3.5.0+(Microsoft+Windows+NT+6.2.9200.0) - 500 0 0 31
```

The following event is logged (shown in the event viewer) in the nuget server:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 27/03/2017 10:40:17 
Event time (UTC): 27/03/2017 07:40:17 
Event ID: cb897ce6dc2f4e40a07c71a9160718f2 
Event sequence: 2073 
Event occurrence: 4 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/MainRepository-1-131350724531418170 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /MainRepository 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\NugetServerInternal\ 
    Machine name: NUGET-SRV 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 2512 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: some.domain/some.user 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: IndexOutOfRangeException 
    Exception message: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Web.HttpRawUploadedContent.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Web.HttpMultipartContentTemplateParser.GetNextLine()
   at System.Web.HttpMultipartContentTemplateParser.ParseIntoElementList()
   at System.Web.HttpMultipartContentTemplateParser.Parse(HttpRawUploadedContent data, Int32 length, Byte[] boundary, Encoding encoding)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetMultipartContent()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFilesCollection()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureFiles()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Files()
   at System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper.get_Files()
   at NuGet.Server.Publishing.PackageService.CreatePackage(HttpContextBase context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://nuget-srv/MainRepository/nuget/ 
    Request path: /MainRepository/nuget/ 
    User host address: 192.168.1.30 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: some.domain/some.user 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 19 
    Thread account name: some.domain/some.user 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.HttpRawUploadedContent.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Web.HttpMultipartContentTemplateParser.GetNextLine()
   at System.Web.HttpMultipartContentTemplateParser.ParseIntoElementList()
   at System.Web.HttpMultipartContentTemplateParser.Parse(HttpRawUploadedContent data, Int32 length, Byte[] boundary, Encoding encoding)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetMultipartContent()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFilesCollection()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureFiles()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Files()
   at System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper.get_Files()
   at NuGet.Server.Publishing.PackageService.CreatePackage(HttpContextBase context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

**NOTE: per my checking sometime the package is created in the packages folder and sometime is not.
NOTE: I am pretty sure that all configuration is in place (including API key etc..). Of course, will be glad to know what is missing though.**

Will appreciate any advice on this one.

Many thanks in advance,
Ofer

Comment: Forgot to mention that per my checking both failed and pass nuspec files look the same except additional dependencies in the failed one, whicih I am trying to investigate with DEV team.

Comment: Could it be that something wrong with the package you want to install. For those 1-3 projects, did you test to install other nuget package, maybe a simple package, could it install successfully? And if other project using this package get the same error?

Comment: Please use some tools like [Fiddler](http://fiddler.en.lo4d.com/) to monitor the network when this issue happened. Is there something wrong with the network?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am trying to figure out (using wireshark) the gaps between the bad & the good push requests. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Did you increase the package version before push it?

Comment: AFAIK,  don't have to if I turn on the following NuGet server conflagration: <add key="allowOverrideExistingPackageOnPush" value="true" />

Comment: Captured and compared both good and bad HTTP PUT requests with both Fiddler and Wireshark - there is no special gaps BUT the length of their content (naturally). Additionally, I have raised the same NuGet server (web application) in other machine and I have been able to push the "problematic" package their :-). My general assumption from this attempt, is some additional or missing program / feature that make the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poor answer though, but still one that might help any potential issues you guys encounter :-).

I've realized that my "problematic" push requests had worked against newly created NuGet server. The new one was Windows Server 2012 R2 too. I've just raised it clean and added ONLY the necessary windows features to support the IIS/web operations against the Nuget server.

If I am not mistaken it was only ASP.NET 4.5.

Best regards,
Ofer